# Phpbb can not detect mysql database

Tags: php, phpbb3

Things done:

- Read few tutorials including https://www.phpbb.com/community/docs/INSTALL.html#quickinstall

I have checked that database user owns a database.

Phpinfo() displays support for the mysql (it does not displays my particular database info, should it?)

I am trying to install phpbb on virtual private server. Files have been downloaded and uzipped as per tutorials.

Priviledges have been changed as per attatched link.

Earlier I had problems with mysql and mariadb so I purged all of it and installed new mysql.

Still the message appears:

"You must have support for at least one compatible database within PHP. If no database modules are shown as available you should contact your hosting provider or review the relevant PHP installation documentation for advice."

I am not using ftp.

I have installed phpbb on my local machine in the past, never on vps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error is pointing towards the unavailability of a PHP MySQL driver. Please install the MySQLi driver on your server.

```
apt-get install php7.1-mysql
```

Replace 7.1 with the version you're using.

Comment: Thanks for a guidance. It pushed me in right direction. I actually was unable to install php7.1-mysql. What helped was purgeing php and reinstalling current version. Then phpbb guided me to install additional packages.